# Как передать payloads между сообщениями используя VK API?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, callback

К примеру бот мне отправил текстовое сообщение с payload т.е. messeges.send(payload="тут что то"). Как мне его словить, отправив сообщение в ответ?

Answer (score 0):

"F12 в браузере и смотреть закладку network, кликнуть на нужном запросе и посмотреть payload (данные, отправляемые запросом серверу)" –
Dmitry Kozlov
15 июн в 15:51

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).